# How to get the URL in the middleware in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel

i have project on laravel 5.5
im using middleware 
and this is the code

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class roleMiddleware
{
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // if code to check where the url is 
    // code here
    //else
    //code here
    //else
    //code
    //return $next($request);
}
}
```

so i need code to check where the request come from 
and if it == something do this
if it == something else do that

Comment: how can i get the url the request come from  in the middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inside of your middleware:

```
$request->url(); // without query string
```

With query string you can use:

```
$request->fullUrl();
```

For more Request methods, see Illuminate\Http\Request.php class.